# ViewControllers inside UIScrollView not Visible swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I'm trying to add ViewControllers in UIScrollView and VC's are loaded from xib. This is my code

```
let onevc = OneViewController()
self.addChildViewController(onevc )
self.scrollView.addSubview(onevc .view)
onevc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

let twovc = TwoViewController()
var frame:CGRect = twovc.view.frame
frame.origin.x = 320
twovc.view.frame = frame
self.addChildViewController(twovc)
self.scrollView.addSubview(twovc.view)
twovc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(640, self.view.frame.size.height)
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
```

Both the viewcontrollers are added but they are not visible, scrollview is just showing white screen. I have added few elements in ViewControllers and also to test I added **println("something")** So when the view is loaded, It is printing **something** but not showing anything. what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you forgot to specify the nib name for the view controller?

```
let onevc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OneViewController")

or 

let onevc = OneViewController(nibName: "OneViewController", bundle: nil)
```

Same goes for the 2nd one.

Comment: how do I perform with this  code? if i have a button in my OneVC and if i create segue with that button. i get error because this vc is added as subview. So whats the best way to perform segues?